# How to get the value from the URL

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to get the value from the URL dynamically. Could you please help achieve this?

Request URL:

`requestForm/intakeReqDetails/3210/request`

Expected Reponse:

`3210`

I can achieve this using the substring method, but the index number should be hardcoded. Can you please get a better solution?

Comment: Since you tagged `spring-boot`: Just inject the value as a `@PathParam`

Comment: @Jorn this should be an answer, maybe you can give a short code snippet as an example

Comment: @Joshua It's more of a hint to go in that direction, than a full answer. If someone wants to make it *into* a full answer, they are welcome to.

Answer (score 1):

I think with this method you can retrieve what you want :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponents.html#getPathSegments()

Answer (score 0):

I will complete @Guillaume response, he suggest to use a spring util class but in java we have [Class URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) with such a great methods, just have a look at get methods.

Or how @Jorn suggest use `@PathVariable`

```
@GetMapping(path = "/requestForm/intakeReqDetails/{messageId}/request")
public String getInfo(@PathVariable Integer messageId) {
 return "message id: " + messageId;
}
```